# Shifting from Cmin to Cmaj in guitar solo

Tags: theory, guitar

I'm playing a guitar solo by myself without accompaniment where I move from C major to C minor by playing D diminished as a passing chord. How should I move back to C major from C minor?

I am interested in  the different ways one can shift from minor to major.

Comment: How about G, which is the dominant in both modes? The problem here is that there are many equally “right” answers to this question. In fact switching between parallel major/minor is much less of a big deal than modulation; it might not take anything special, just … switch! (See Die Moldau)

Comment: First, this isn’t really a site for creative feedback or input. Second, Beethoven freely moved between major and minor and you can also. It’s definitely not something that requires a lot of care - you can literally substitute a major chord for a minor one. Experiment with a few ideas and pick the one you like best.

Comment: But the more important information to include is, are you playing a guitar solo (all by yourself and unaccompanied), or a solo moment in a piece that includes other players.  We need to know what the other players are instructed to do in order to answer clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can simply jump straight from C major to C minor and back.  This is a change of *mode* (major-minor) but not a change of *tonic* (C is still the "home note") and so the change does not require a modulation.

If you are seeking to soften the change of mode, which can be jarring, here is one additional idea.  Find a way to use some of the notes that will change *before* you formally change.  From major to minor adds three flats.  In this case, C minor uses Eb, Ab, and Bb but C Major uses E, A, and B.  So utilizing these notes in their altered form can make it less jarring.

**C Major to C minor**
Use an Ab from time to time before you change.  This can be done with a G7b9 or Bdim7 chord, as you know.  You can also use an Fm in C major, which gives a hint of Ab.  It can be as simple as a short C-Fm-C moment, but it puts the Ab in our ear.

**C minor to C Major**
Making some use of the melodic minor scale and the progression F-G-Cm.  This lets us get used to A and B natural before we get all the way into C major.

Comment: Tried it, adding some dissonance that also hints the major scale works. I tried C Melodic minor and C dim scale before moving on to Cmaj and it sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

Do is not too far from G7♭9 , so going from Do to G7♭9 will take you to either C or Cm, sounding good either way.

Comment: Waaaay too early to choose - other parts of the world aren't even awake yet!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Nike modulation - 'Just do it!'  You can separate them by their common dominant, G7, if you really want to.  But there's no need.  It's a very small move.  But, presumably, you're making it because you want to HEAR the contrast.  Why do you feel the need to smooth it out?

Comment: Nike modulation,.Already shifted one from Cmaj to Cmin and the shift to C min sounds cool . I'm need to smooth it out because I want to learn to transition from minor to major smoothly, that's the sound I'm after not the dramatic transition

Comment: C major to F# major is dramatic!   C major to C minor is about as close as you can get!  But sure, go for a little walk-round if you like.